# Queue of BackgroundWorkers raise event when complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, backgroundworker, parallel.for

I need to execute *n* BackgroundWorkers, when they're complete I want to raise an event and do something with the result of all their work. My use case it to make the queue, fill it, then run it only once. To accomplish this I made a class ParallelQueue. With my initial testing it seems to work, however I'm concerned that the condition `_max == _iteration` is not the best was to evaluate all work in the queue has been done. Or that my use of Queue is not thread safe, what should I use to accomplish this? (ConcurrentQueue?) If this question is too general I'll remove it, Thanks.

```
public class ParallelQueue
{
    private Queue<BackgroundWorker> _queue;
    private readonly object _key = new object();
    private int _max = 0;
    private int _iteration = 0;
    private bool _ran = false;

    public ParallelQueue()
    {
        _queue = new Queue<BackgroundWorker>();
    }

    public delegate void BackgroundQueueCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e);
    public event BackgroundQueueCompleted QueueCompleted;

    public void Add(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
        _queue.Enqueue(worker);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        lock (_key)
        {
            if(!_queue.Any()) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ParallelQueue cannot be empty");
            if (_ran) throw new InvalidOperationException("ParallelQueue can only be run once");
            _ran = true;

            _max = _queue.Count();
            Parallel.For(0, _queue.Count, (i, state) =>
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = _queue.Dequeue();
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            });
        }
    }

    private void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _iteration);
        if (_max == _iteration)
        {
            QueueCompleted?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

example using ParallelQueue

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var queue = new ParallelQueue();
        queue.QueueCompleted += MyQueueCompletedHandler;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            });
            queue.Add(bw);
        }

        queue.Run();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void MyQueueCompletedHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("queue is complete");
    }
}
```

Comment: First, i would add a check for `_ran` in `Add` method... You don't want users adding workers after it's started or finished.

Comment: There is no reason to make this wrap a `Queue` -- you aren't doing anything `Queue`-specific. You could just make it a `List`. Then do a `Parallel.ForEach` on the list and empty it when you are done.

Comment: Anyway -- with what you have, it should be fine how you are checking for an "end state". I am trying to think of a way that `WorkerCompleted` wouldn't get called. That's the only instance where this would fail.

Comment: You shouldnt be using background workers or `Parrellel.For`/`ForEach` with *IO bound workloads* (`async`) they are tying up thread / thread pool resources, when they can be queued by your hardware / OS using *IO completion ports*

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundWorker` class has become practically obsolete after the introduction of the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) (TPL) in 2010. If the results of the work you have to do is homogeneous, you can just use the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method, or, if you are familiar with LINQ, use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq). Here is a PLINQ example:

```
var input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int[] results = input
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered() // optional
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2) // optional
    .Select(x => { Thread.Sleep(500); return x * 2; }) // simulate some work
    .ToArray();
```

If the results are heterogeneous, you can create a [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) for each piece of work, store it in a `List<Task>`, wait all the tasks, and get the results through the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) property of each. Example:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); return 1; });
var task2 = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); return "Helen"; });
var task3 = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); return DateTime.Now; });
var list = new List<Task>() { task1, task2, task3 };
Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
int result1 = task1.Result;
string result2 = task2.Result;
DateTime result3 = task3.Result;
```