# Parallel processing using concurrent collection

Tags: c#, async-await, queue, task-parallel-library, concurrentdictionary

I currently have a function that perform a set of 10 tasks in parallel. After the 10 tasks completes i move on to the next 10 until my queue is empty. I am looking forward to increase the efficiency of that algorithm as right now if 9 of my tasks have completed in 1 min and my 10th task is taking another 10 min i need to wait for all the 10 task to complete even though i have 9 spot free for 9 other task to start using.

Is there a way that when a task is completed, i immediately send another task for processing within that same level(for each loop). I saw that concurrent Dictionary can be use. Can you please guide and provide some sample code.

```
public async Task Test()
{

List<task> listoftasks =new List<Task>();

foreach(level in levels)
{
    Queue<Model1> queue=new Queue<Model1>(Store);
   
   while(queue.Count>0)
   {
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(!queue.TryDequeue(out Model1 item))
            {
                break;
            }
            listoftasks.Add(Task.Run(()=>Dosomething(sql)))
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(listoftasks);
        listoftasks .Clear();    
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue`

Comment: @Charlieface can you ellaborate please

Comment: Run the `while(queue.Count>0)` on the inside of `task.Run` *also*, so that each thread dequeues an item and ends when the queue is empty. Use `ConcurrentQueue` for thread-safety

Comment: try TPL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: @Charlieface can you show some code

Comment: Is there a reason that you you are trying to implement manually functionality that is already available by lots of built-in libraries, like the `Parallel` class, the PLINQ and the TPL Dataflow library?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Its my first time with concurrent collection, can you point me out to some code

Comment: You can see a PLINQ example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354440/how-to-convert-parallel-for-to-plinq). Basically it's just Linq with the addition of `AsParallel`. Very easy and concise. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696497/queue-of-backgroundworkers-raise-event-when-complete/63701479#63701479) is another example.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias can you provide some code related to my code. the second link you mention having the list of task is exactly the code i have.

Comment: Keshav I'm not sure what kind of code to show. The code in your question doesn't seem to be intended for solving a specific problem. It's more like trying to build a generic tool for solving a range of possible problems. In a comment in Charlieface's answer you mentioned the keyword `await`. If your workload is asynchronous, please forget about `Parallel` and PLINQ. These are not async-friendly. Instead take a look at 00110001's answer, who suggested using an `ActionBlock`. The TPL Dataflow library is an excellent tool for doing asynchronous work.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` to achieve desired behavour (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0). In this case you can just push all tasks at one moment and they will be executed with desired level of concurrency (not more then 10 tasks at the parallel in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You can get each Task to dequeue an item. Use a `ConcurrentQueue` to ensure thread-safety.

It's kind of a poor-man's scheduler, but it's very lightweight.

```cs
ConcurrentQueue<Model1> queue;

void Dequeue()
{
   while(queue.TryDequeue(out var item))
       DoSomething(item);
}

public async Task Test()
{
    queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Model1>(Store);
    var listoftasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
        listoftasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Dequeue()));
    
    await Task.WhenAll(listoftasks);
}
```

**Note:** this does not handle exceptions, so all exceptions must be handled or swallowed

Comment: can i remove listoftasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Dequeue()))   to listoftasks.Add(Dequeue)

Comment: No because then it won't run on another thread

Comment: This approach is quite similar with how the built-in libraries work internally. But in order to robustify this approach, much more code is needed. Your current implementation will not behave well in case of exceptions. What will happen is that one worker-task will be killed on every exception, and the process will continue with a reduced degree of parallelism. If you are unlucky to have exactly `Environment.ProcessorCount - 1` early exceptions, the last standing worker will slowly process all items alone, until the exceptions are finally surfaced.

Comment: True, I would only use this when I'm swallowing or dealing with all exceptions in the inner function. I **did** say it's lightweight.

Comment: "Basic", "untested", "non production-ready" may be more accurate terms. Being lightweight is a desirable quality to have IMHO. :-) Btw I upvoted your answer. It's not that bad really. 

Comment: @Charlieface can you clarify please. doesn't the for loop run only once and  all item in the list are being dequeue in a single task. Mydequeue method is  async task deuqueu() and inside it await another method for processing

Comment: @keshav No. What happens is the `for` loop creates `ProcessorCount` number of threads, each of those continually dequeues items until the queue is empty. Note the point made about exceptions

Comment: To your defense I should add that the father of TPL, Stephen Toub, has posted some years ago a solution that suffers from the same problem. It is the last `ForEachAsync` method in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) article.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias have clarified that. I wouldn't call it untested, I use this often, always in instances where each run of `DoSomething()` would catch and store errors anyway. I did it recently in a PDF to image converter.

Comment: Why would you use this method for PDF => image conversion, instead of using the `Parallel` class or the PLINQ? These are certainly well-tested libraries. What more do you get by using a home made mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use an `ActionBlock` (out of the TPL Dataflow library). It has

1. built in `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`
2. Can easily deal with `async` *IO Bound workloads*, or non `async` *CPU Bound* workloads
3. Has *cancelation* support (if needed)
4. Can be built into larger pipelines
5. Can run as perpetual consumer in a multi-producer environment

**Given**

```
private ActionBlock<Model> _processor;
```

**Setup**

```
_processor = new ActionBlock<Model>(
   DoSomething,
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
   {
      CancellationToken = SomeCancelationTokenIfNeeded,
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
      SingleProducerConstrained = true
   });
```

**Some Method**

```
public static void DoSomething(Model item)
{ ... }
```

**Usage**

```
await _processor.SendAsync(someItem);
```